# How to Create Excel sheet through script

Tags: shell

I want to know is it possible to write shell script for creating a excel sheet.I also want to read,edit and delete cells in that spread sheet.

Comment: Since newer Excel versions use XML format, it is doable. There are some libraries to handle the complex structure. If perl is an option, you will be able to find one.

Comment: The easiest way would be separate your values with any delimiter, mostly used is commas and import the file to MS excel or google sheets. This way you can reduce the complexity of your code and utilise the features already implemented in spreadsheet tools.